# UTF-8 character with font-weight property

Tags: html, css, unicode

font-weight property doesn't work for lower than 300 value and Unicode font.

It is Helvetica and font-weight: 300;
Unicode characters still bold. What can i use?

[image]

Comment: Which browser and OS are you using? Does this occur in all browsers? Do you have a sample page online?

Comment: What if you say `font-weight: bold`?

Comment: @j0nes, i'm using chrome on mac os x.

Comment: @KerrekSB, font-weight bold working great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To present text in book weight (`font-weight: 300` in CSS), you need a font with that weight containing all the characters you need. Apparently, you have Helvetica in book weight in your computer (the vast majority of users don’t have it, or any Helvetica) but with a limited character repertoire that lacks many letters used in Turkish. Therefore the browser picks them up from some other font, quite possibly of normal (400) weight.

If you really want book weight text, then the best option is to use a downloadable font, also known as web font. Most fonts that people have on their computers are available in normal and bold weight only, or possibly in normal weight only. Check out [Google web fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) and [FontSquirrel @font-face Kits](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface) to see whether they have something that suits your design. Unfortunately, free fonts that you can easily use have very often a rather limited character repertoire.

Answer (score 2):

I guess Helvetica does not support these characters and that's why it displays it in Arial font. My suggestion would be to change to the font which supports your alphabet out of the box (Arial supports almost every language you can think of).

Comment: Would using HTML special characters instead of unicode ones make a difference if it's a problem with the font?

Comment: Yup, blob8108, you're right, it will not. That's because in Unicode all characters will be included. Edited that one out. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: i tried Arial but font-family:arial; font-weight: 300 equal font-family:helvetica; font-weight:600. i want to use thin font.